# How to draw beyond the emulator screen in android

Tags: android, imageview, draw

can any one there help me to draw a rectangle on the Image View which is set as background of image whose size is bigger than emulator size(So it has horizontal and vertical scroll bar)..
I want to draw rectangle at right most corner of the image..so that drawn rectangle is shown only when the image is scrolled to that position..
Please suggest me with code also..
Thank You in advance..

Comment: take a large image and insert it in `src`. and make imageview inside scrollview

Comment: i did it...now i want to draw lines on that big image...So please tell me the next solution for it

Answer (score 0):

take a large image and insert it in src. and make imageview inside scrollview.